# Xamarin forms CollectionView data in two columns does not align in lines on iOs

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, collectionview

I have a problem on iOs. On android CollectionView items aligns perfect, but on iOS not. Screenshots: 
Android screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7v2lK.png 
iOs screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCwsa.jpg 

My code:

```html
 <CollectionView x:Name="FlowersList" VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" >
                    <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                        <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical" x:Name="grid_layout" Span="2" />
                    </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate >
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="nuline_row" Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="pirma_row" Height="Auto"/>
                                    <RowDefinition x:Name="antra_row" Height="*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition x:Name="nulinis_stulpelis"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Row="0" 
                                       Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageConverter}}"
                                       Aspect="AspectFill"                                    
                                       VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                                       HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                </Image>
                                <Label Grid.Row="1" 
                                       Text="{Binding Name, Converter={StaticResource caseConverter}, ConverterParameter=u}"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                                       VerticalOptions="Start" />
                                <Label Grid.Row="2"
                                       Text="{Binding PriceToDisplay, StringFormat='{0} €'}"
                                       FontSize="16"
                                       TextColor="Black"
                                       LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                                       VerticalOptions="Start" Padding="0,-5,0,20" />
                                <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnTapGestureRecognizerTapped"
                                                              NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />

                                </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                            </Grid>

                        </DataTemplate>
                    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                </CollectionView>
```

I have out of ideas. Maybe someone know how to solve this problem?

Comment: specify a height value, or use ItemSizing - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/layout#item-sizing

Comment: Or try to just set a "HeightRequest" for the image.

Comment: Was a solution found? I am having the same issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may caused by the size of image is different by default:

**Solution**:

1.Give a specific height in the Grid:

```
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="nuline_row" Height="150"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="pirma_row" Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition x:Name="antra_row" Height="*"/>
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

2.Or give a heightRequest to Image:

```
<Image Grid.Row="0" 
    Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource Base64ToImageConverter}}"
    HeightRequest="150"
    Aspect="AspectFill"                                    
    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
</Image>
```

Comment: It doesn't help. Still the same issue.

Comment: Try to add `ItemSizingStrategy="MeasureFirstItem"`.

Comment: Have you use them along with RowDefinition = 150?

Answer (score 0):

just upgrade xamrin Froms Version.

[Xamarin.Forms CollectionView Introduction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/collectionview/introduction)

Comment: Tried, even pre release not helps.

Answer (score 0):

I have also ran into simular problems with using grids like this inside Data Templates on iOS. I can't explain why it's not working reliable, but I managed to work around it by switching to stacklayout + putting the HeightRequest="150" on the Image. Seen as you're basically using the grid as a vertical stack, you might want to try this one.